# WPF. Why is the selected value not displayed in the DataGridComboBoxColumn elements of a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, combobox, datagrid

I am developing a WPF program in which I need to display a table, for which I decided to use a `DataGrid`, in which one of its columns is a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, for the `DisplayMemberPath` property I am using a column from a `DataTable`, but the `ComboBox` does not work correctly, It displays the list of options associated with it, but when you select any, it simply closes as if you had not selected anything.

Here is what you see when you select an option from the ComboBox:

[Selected option in the ComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCWYT.png)

Here it is shown that if there are selectable elements:

[ComboBox options dispayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx2ha.png)

I am configuring the DataGridComboBox as follows:

```cs
DataGridComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();

comboBoxColumn.Header = columnName;
comboBoxColumn.DisplayMemberPath = dataColumn;
comboBoxColumn.SelectedValuePath = columnName;
comboBoxColumn.ItemsSource = table1.DefaultView;
comboBoxColumn.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding(indexColumn);
```

Where:

- columnName is a variable that contains the name of the column that contains the index
- dataColumn is a variable that contains the name of the column that contains the value of interest
- indexColumn is a variable containing the name of the column that contains the index of the initial value that the DataGridComboBoxColumn should display
- table1 is the name of the reference DataTable

I have a theory that the only problem is how to bind the DisplayMemberPath property
But after doing a little research, I find that they always link the columns of the DataTable with the comboBox in the same way.

Could someone advise me or show me what my mistake is?

Comment: Does `table1` include a column named `indexColumn` to store the currently selected value?

Comment: No, it does'n have it. Is it necessary for the purpose?

Comment: You need to store the value to be displayed somewhere.